# Which table should the foreign key refer?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the following table.

```
Entity (ID, EntityType),
Tickets (TicketId, ..., (TicketId refers Entity (ID)),
Contacts (ContactId, ..., (ContactId refers Entity (ID)).
```

I want to duplicate Ticket data in another table,

```
TicketsDup (TicketID, ...).
```

In TicketsDup table TicketID should refer Entity table or Tickets table?

The point of TicketsDup is to store only active tickets. So inactive tickets will be deleted from TicketsDup table. But will still be stored in Tickets Table. The user can mark a ticket as active. In which case the ticket has to be inserted into TicketsDup table. Also modified time has to be updated in Tickets table. This is where my concern is. Mysql locks parent rows from getting updated when a child row is being inserted. This causes deadlock. Is it wrong to refer Entity table for TicketsDup table? I hope the question is not vague.

Comment: Is the Tickets table going to be too large to have an index IsActive column be an efficient way to find the currently-active tickets?

Comment: Yeah. It will be too large. And there are a lot of varchar columns where the user can apply complex criteria. I want the data to be queried within 100ms. Also there are a lot of inactive data. We want to avoid querying inactive data. Thats why we are going for archiving data.

Comment: A deadlock can only happen if (at least) two transactions are involved, e.g. one that's updating the parent row and *a different transaction* that inserts the child row. If that's the case it would look strange, and you might want to investigate and probably change that (unless there's a good reason for it). As far as I understood it, it has only, if at all, only indirectly to do with the foreign key. In general, you may want to think about design changes (e.g. test just proper indexes, or an actual archive table where you *move* (not duplicate) old tickets to a 2nd table (or use partitions).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write every new ticket to the STORE table and then duplicate it in the ACTIVE table. So you don't get any problems with the id field.

If the ticket in the ACTIVE table is closed you copy the data into the STORE table and remove it from the active table.

If you search for an ticket you search the ACTIVE table first and then in the STORE table.

If a ticket in the STORE table is marked for active you copy it back to the ACTIVE table.

But if you don't have that many tickets I would stick to one table only. I have 6 years of tickets in one table and its not getting slower. Just mark them active and nonactive. I don't even delete a ticket just mark it deleted.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some queries to show where your problem is.

Comment: I have about 2crore tickets. and I happen to have a child table which has custom fields. Many of the columns in customfields table is varchar. And the users use a lot of contains queries. It takes me 5 seconds to get 50 tickets out of this table everytime a complex query comes. Thats why Im going for archiving. Our design is to have all tickets in one table(T1) and active tickets alone in other table(T2). For some reason the if the user wants to see both inactive and active tickets, T1 will be queried. With your design this won't be possible right?

Comment: If you queries takes that long it is wise tot look if each field that is in the queries are indexed properly. You should easaly go over 100K of tickets before noticing any slow behavior. Also the way you build the queries is a point. don't fetch all fields it you need just a subset.Perheps you could give an query example that is slow.

Comment: I'm sorry. But why do you keep asking me to change my design. No one seems to willing to answer my actual question. The current design is the best I can have which can solve all my use case. I already told you I have more than 2 crore tickets. you keep talking about 1million tickets. The queries get complex if a user applies criteria on 10 different fields. And if all of them are contains criteria, Index isn't going to make any difference. So If you can answer my actual question, that would be great.

Comment: Then the answer stands to use the id from the original table where the ticket is created the first time. And keep that id in the duplicate table. If a duplicate ticket becomes active that id should still be available.